# Possible to do this in Python?

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python, and am not sure if this can be done. As you can see, I couldn't even figure out a good title for the question. Say I have 2 classes,

```
class A:
    self.B = None

class B:
    def c(self):
        pass

    def d(self):
        pass
```

Now if I make an instance of the class,

```
a = A()
a.b = B()
```

I want something like,

```
print a.c()
```

And this should internally call:

```
a.b.c()
```

Comment: Possible?? http://xkcd.com/413/

Comment: The ability to do something - particularly in Python - does not mean that it is not a colossally bad idea.

Comment: My first question is, why not just use a `B` object? Why wrap it in an `A` object at all? I guess you have a good reason, but you should say what it is. There are many ways to accomplish things like this, and we can only say which is the best if you tell us about your actual problem in more detail.

Comment: Agree with @Thomas Carpenter: colossally bad idea.  Makes something simple very, very obscure.

Answer (score 2):

Have [`A.__getattr__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) catch the access to `a.c` and have it return `a.b.c` instead.

Comment: Thanks @ignacio. This looks like what I want. I'm thinking of using __getattribute__ instead to override A's attribute values. The only problem is how do I avoid infinite recursion? The behaviour I want is that when a.test() is called below, it should check if B has 'test' defined, if not the return A's version of test

Comment: @Akash: While you can do this, it's complicated and ugly. There's probably a better way to write the code you want - I think subclassing might be what you're after, but it's not quite clear from your example.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want it to work like that? Have A inherit from B if it is going to be understood as having B's methods.

Comment: To clarify, define B first, and then `class A(B):`

Answer (score 1):

```
class A:
    self.B = None
```

This won't compile. What does self refer to? Perhaps you meant the following?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = None

a = A()
a.b = B()
```

As @Ignacio said, use **getattr** or make A inherit from B as follows:

```
class A(B):
    ...
```

Comment: This also won't compile :). You left the `def` off `__init__`.